# lambda expression with aggregation function

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to learn lambda expression from Microsoft website and I am trying to apply it to a scenario I create to get deeper understanding of what the site is trying to demonstrate. I stumble in the aggregate function that associates with linq and lambda. Please advise what is the correct syntax for what I am trying to achieve. Basically, I have a class called item which has 3 properties: category, ID and weight. A category can have multiple IDs associated with it and I am thinking of getting the total weight of a category which is the sum of all individual weight of each IDs that has the category I specified.
More specifically, this is the extract of my structure:

```
class item
    {
        public int NodeID
        { get; set; }
        public int Weight
        { get; set; }
        public int Category
        { get; set; }
    }
```

I have the following dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int,item> _itemsReceivedList=new Dictionary<int,item>();
```

And this is where I tried to get the total weight of a category c:

```
_itemsReceivedList.Select(x=>x.Value.Category==c)
.Sum( what should I put here for the predicate? )
```

I wanted to sum the weight of each item that has category c.
Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not filter. It projects the elements into something else. Here you project the elements into bools. Use [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var sum = _itemsReceivedList
            .Where(x=>x.Value.Category==c)
            .Sum(x=>x.Value.Weight);
```

Comment: Thank you all for your lightning fast responses. I did try this but this is what I got as error: Error 4 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'Weight' and no extension method 'Weight' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: the `x` in the last statement is still a KeyValuePair.

Comment: @L.B: I still have the same error. Maybe x=>x.Value.Weight is not the correct predicate of Func<bool,int> ? This is where I got fuzzy.

Comment: @user1205746 Did you really copy the given answer into your code? Please note that your use of `Select` was wrong. It must be `Where`.

Answer (score 3):

```
int weight = _itemsReceivedList.Where(x => x.Value.Category == c)
                               .Select(s => s.Value)
                               .Sum(item => item.Weight);
```

I assume that `c` is declared somewhere else as an `int`

[image: ScreenPrint]

Comment: Yes, Sam. c is int but I got this:  Error 4 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'Weight' and no extension method 'Weight' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: this worked when I just tested it.. I will upload a screenshot

Answer (score 2):

Write this

```
_itemsReceivedList.Where(x=>x.Value.Category==c).Sum(x => x.Weight);
```

Comment: This is wrong: `Select` with a boolean expression returns an `IEnumerable<bool>`.

Comment: this is very common mistake. You are confusing a .Select() with a .Where()